# Verilog if statement always returns false

Tags: verilog

I need help with my `if/else` statement that's not working. No matter what I enter, it just doesn't work. It only ever assigns 1 to `operand2`.  What am I doing wrong with the `if/else` statement?

```
module TestMod;                     // the "main" thing
   parameter STDIN = 32'h8000_0000; // I/O address of keyboard input channel

   reg [7:0] str [1:3]; // typing in 2 chars at a time (decimal # and Enter key)
   reg [4:0] X, Y;      // 5-bit X, Y to sum
   wire [4:0] S;        // 5-bit Sum to see as result
   wire C5;             // like to know this as well from result of Adder
   reg operand, operand2;  //operand
   wire E;              //exception overflow inidicator

   AddSub addOrSub(X, Y, S, C5, E, operand2);

   initial begin
      $display("Enter X (two digit 00~15 (since max is 01111)):");
      ...


      $display("Enter Y (two digit 00~15 (since max is 01111)):");
      ...


      $display("Enter + or -");
      operand = $fgetc(STDIN);
      if (operand == "+") begin
        operand2 = 0;
      end
      else begin
        operand2 = 1;
      end


      #1; // wait until Adder getsthem processed
      $display("operand", operand);
      $display("X =",X, " (%b",X, ")  Y =",Y, " (%b",Y,")", "C0=",operand2);
      $display("Result =", S," (%b",S, ")  C5 = ",C5);

   end
endmodule
```

Comment: So operand2 not equal 1 or 0?

Comment: operand2 always equals 1 even when I enter "+" into my string

Comment: I meant to have it as operand = $fgetc(STDIN). If I switch the statments to       if (operand == "-") begin
        operand2 = 1;
      end
      else begin
        operand2 = 0;
      end then  operand2 is always 0 and vice versa

Comment: Got it to work needed reg[7:0] for my operand

Comment: That makes sense: in C I would not use that code as the return key is not processed and may get in your way. Here it was probably added to the operand. It may still interfere when you try to run the code in a loop!

Answer (score 1):

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.3.4.1 *Reading a character at a time*, `$fgetc`:

> reads a **byte** from the file

A byte is 8 bits.  If the user inputs `+` on STDIN, then `$fgetc` returns the string `+`, which in a numeric context is represented by the ASCII value 43.

You declared `operand` to be `reg`, which is a 1-bit value.  Therefore, `operand` can only take on the value 0 or 1.  In the case where `$fgetc` returns the string `+`, which is 43 (or 'b0010_1011), `operand` just gets the LSB, which is 1.

`(operand == "+")` compares 1 to 43, which is false, and the `else` code is executed.

As you pointed out in a Comment, you need to declare operand as 8 bits wide:

```
reg [7:0] operand;
```